# What's the production cost of a typical gene therapy drug?

Tags: gene-therapy

Current gene therapy drugs are notorious for being expensive (>500k USD). What's the production cost of a typical gene therapy drug, excluding the research and development costs?

---

(The question is neutral: this isn't meant to be a criticism against gene therapy drug prices, which I understand need to offset research and development costs, and should be [compared](https://www.biopharmadive.com/news/bluebird-sets-18m-price-tag-for-blood-disease-gene-therapy/556923/) against the price of non-gene-therapy treatments)

Comment: I'm going to be surprised if such information is publicly available. I think pharmaceutical companies would view it as sensitive business information they wouldn't want competitors to know.

Comment: @CareyGregory one could estimate via reverse engineering / looking at what the drug contains.